# Lutron 120v 5a dimmer switch replace with to 3 speed pull switch?

Tags: electrical

I have a universal electrical motor (for a home wall fan) that came shipped with a Lutron 120v 5amp rated slide dimmer control to regulate it's speed.

No rating listed on the motor itself. Two wires (and a ground) coming out of the motor casing.

Is it possible/practical to build my own 3 speed, pull switch control?

I am guessing that I would just need to get two, proper resistors with matching heatsinks and wire them to a 3 way switch.

One circuit open.
One circuit no resistor.
Two circuits with varying resistors to lower the fan speed.

It seems that no such thing exists for sale...

And, although I have done plenty of off-the-shelf installation of auto & home electric, I have never created custom circuitry like this.

Thank you much,
Nathan

Comment: the dimmer doesn't use resistors, and neither should you; that's a fire hazard as-described. if i were you, i would use the existing dimmer on whatever "medium" setting i want, then use the switch to choose between disconnected, connected via the dimmer, and connected via un-altered AC (yielding off, low, high). add a 2nd dimmer if desired.

Comment: Read the article on Wikipedia for a Universal Motor and you will see they don't use resistors to control the speed. This hasn't been done since the very very old days of controlling the speed of a D.C. motor. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_motor